# Have users choose different pictures for bootstrap carousel

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, coldfusion

I have a landing page with bootstrap carousel rotating through 3 pictures with text to the right. My client is wanting to have an admin page where I show pictures available to choose from along with a text box for them to enter in custom text. I have already created the page for them to choose and add text and that gets inserted into the SQL DB using ColdFusion. I have ran a query to grab the records but when I do the `cfloop` inside the carousel the three images they have chosen show up all together. I am not even sure it can be done this way. Here is my output code:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">
            <cfloop query="getPreview">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img class="img-responsive center-block" data-id="0" src="#getPreview.landingPage_image#" alt="" width="300" height="200"></img>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4 text.center" style="margin: 5px;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 18px">#getPreview.img_text#</div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img data-id="2" src="#getPreview.landingPage_image#" alt="" width="440" height="325" style="margin: -10px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text.center" style="margin: 20px;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 18px">#getPreview.img_text#</div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img data-id="3" src="#getPreview.landingPage_image#" alt="" width="440" height="325" style="margin: -10px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text.center" style="margin: 20px;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 18px">#getPreview.img_text#</div>
            </cfloop>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by **but when I do the cfloop inside the carousel the three images they have chosen show up all together.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your are looping it though all three for every result from your query.

You need to remove two of the items and address the data-id tag, probably with a simple counter.

try somethng like this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item active">
        <div class="row">

            <cfset counter = 1>
            <cfloop query="getPreview">
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <img data-id="#counter#" src="#getPreview.landingPage_image#" alt="" width="440" height="325" style="margin: -10px;">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-4 text.center" style="margin: 20px;margin-top: 50px;font-size: 18px">#getPreview.img_text#</div>
                </div>
                <cfset counter = counter +1>
            </cfloop>
        </div>
    </div>
```